# Error: java: javacTask: source release 8 requires target release 1.8

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-8

I have opened git project I was running under Eclipse previously in IntelliJ. I have changed to Java 8 in following places:

```
File -> Project Structure -> SDKs
```

and

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project
```

Where to set Java 8 else? What it wants?

The project is Maven, pom file has only `dependencies` sections

**UPDATE**

I am trying to run under `IntelliJ`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how can `JAVA_HOME` matter if `IntelliJ` allows per project JDK config? It should use that JDK I configures, all path are known to her.

Comment: Please post the output from the bottom of your IntelliJ build window.  Also, have you tried restarting IntelliJ?

Answer (score 15):

In order to compile your code you should add maven build section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also you can go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler and change it there, but it will cause other developers failures as they need to modify IDE before build

Comment: Why doesn't it takes this information from `IntelliJ` config?

Comment: It takes but it is only for you but not for the other team as .idea folder shouldn't be pushed. More over mvn clean install won't be able to build it as it knows nothing about intellij

Comment: What if I set `1.8` in Maven in `1.7` in `IntelliJ` how will it judge what to use?

Comment: Idea will catch compile plugin and will propose you to change configuration. Anyway until you have target less then maven it will work smoothly. Intellij won't allow you to write 1.8 constructions (they will be built correctly by maven but will be red in editor).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what you have done, you also have to update the build Module.

```
SHIFT + CTRL + ALT + S -> Modules -> Select JDK 1.8 and press apply
```

Check the output from your build to make sure that IntelliJ is using JDK 8 and not the earlier version (7?) which you had.

Comment: I can't update my `JAVA_HOME` each time I run different project with different JDK. `IntelliJ` allows per-project `JDK` config, so it should track `JDK` location automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

For Eclipse:

`Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> add JDK`

You can download the JDK for 1.8 and browse the file when you are trying to add JDK. If it's windows OS then you need to install Java 1.8 and then use the path from `C:\Program Files\...\jdk1.8` (Please refer [this for reference](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm))

The above is for setting eclipse.

Then you need to apply changes for the project setup as below:

`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Click on JRE System Library -> Edit button -> change the Library as 8` that you have set up for eclipse

For IntelliJ, you can try [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html)

Comment: That alone only adds that new JDK to the list of known JDKs. You should add the information that one then has to **pick** that JDK also for a his project.

Comment: This is for Eclipse sorry, I need for IntelliJ